# "property 'storeImage' not found on object type 'UICollectionViewCell'

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i'm trying to subclass cell in order to show images and when i try something like cell.storeImage.image = ...

it says `"property 'storeImage' not found on object type 'UICollectionViewCell'`

i have created a file of UICollectionViewCell and did a IBOutlet for UIImageView and then set the custom class in story board

then i `#import` the .h file and still get the error.

i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

is there a way i can show images without doing this?

my main file where the view controller is run is a UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your custom collectionViewCell

```
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

1) Give cell identifier in Storyboard editor menu.

2) Change cell class to your class in the same menu.

Comment: i already have this: 
`static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` under `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: Are you sure, UICollectionViewCell are your custom cell class?

Comment: `-[UICollectionViewCell storeImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance `

Comment: @farhan change class in storyboard as well

Comment: for what object? 
i did this and the error went away 
`[self.collectionView registerClass:[testCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];`

Comment: @farhan Did you add ImageView to contentView of cell?

Comment: figured it out, looked at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523507/uiimageview-in-custom-uicollectionviewcell-returning-nil-all-the-time