# UICollectionViewCell outlet nil in class but works after using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

There are several posts on nil outlets in a UICollectionViewCell class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165195/why-is-uicollectionviewcells-outlet-nil) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523507/uiimageview-in-custom-uicollectionviewcell-returning-nil-all-the-time), but none of the solutions worked. Using a strong outlet instead of a weak one failed, the `registerClass` solution doesn't apply since the cell doesn't use a custom XIB, the data sources and delegates are wired properly, etc.

In this case, the outlet is a UIImageView which is nil when accessed inside the UICollectionViewCell class, yet works fine when accessed outside.

UICollectionView code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(AlbumCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumCell

    cell.imageView.image = getThumbnail()
    cell.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill        
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.width / 2

    return cell
}
```

UICollectionViewCell code:

```
class AlbumCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        doInit(frame)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        doInit(frame)
    }


    private func doInit(frame: CGRect) {
        // Round corners
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

Rounding corners inside the UICollectionViewCell class fails because `imageView` is nil, yet rounding corners inside of the UICollectionView class succeeds so `imageView` does appear to be connected.

Why is `imageView` nil inside of the UICollectionViewCell class?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try calling `doInit` in `awakeFromNib` however I think the frame may not have been initialized yet *(didn't test that though)*:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  doInit(frame)
}
```

Since you want to update `cornerRadius` with respect to view's frame, I would do that in `layoutSubviews` instead so any frame change will directly reflect to corner radius value:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
}
```

Update: Since you said, you don't use a nib file to load the view, just move `imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true` into `init(frame: CGRect)` and delete `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified that no nib is used ... would this still help?

Comment: Totally. just move `imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true` into `init(frame: CGRect)` and implement `layoutSubviews` like above.

Comment: You don't need to. You can delete it if you don't use nib file. See my update.